# LaTex compilation doesn't generate output

Tags: latex, pdflatex, texnic-center

Can't generate the output of my LaTex document (using TeXnicCenter). At the end of the [log](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/963673/document.log) he says:

> Latex-Result: 0 Error(s), 0
>   Warning(s), 0 Bad Box(es), 0 Page(s)

and correspondingly the viewer says it couldn't find the file.
I have defined the path of the pdf viewer but it didn't help. The path of the source document doesn't contain spaces. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This often happens if compilation stops due to a missing figure or runaway argument. Can you provide more details about the error?

Comment: I take it texnic center is some kind of integrated latex editing environment; that it is supposed to open the output file for you automatically; and that it is not doing so despite not reporting any errors. Yes? Have you tried looking manually in the file system for the output file. If it is present then you know you are looking at a configuration error in texnic center.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much, Steve, but I've just found the problem: I had to change the "Install packages on-the-fly"-setting to "yes" instead of "ask me first".

Comment: You generally use a comment or edit the question (button right under the tags) rather then submit clarifications in an "answer"; because (by design) the view structure of Stack Overflow does not support anything like threading. Please move this content to the question or a comment and delete this.

Comment: Yes-- that is a known bug between texniccenter and miktex.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I uploaded the project zip then this error was shown ,
The fix was to first create blank project then upload the zip file contents.